# How to fix my amazon Ec-2 ip address

Tags: rest, amazon-ec2, webserver

server running on Amazon Ec-2. The web-server acts as back end for my application. My application does a Rest call on the web-server to send or retrieve data.

I want to fix the web-server ip so that even if my web-server crashes or I restart the server I don't need to change the REST call of my application since the address will change in amazon.

My application is a mobile application, is there any way in which I can achieve this so that i can make my mobile application independent from back end .

I know there is something called Elastic Ip but I don't know what it is and how to use it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic IP provides an option to reserve IP address and assign it to your instance. This way you can always have the same IP and it is a right option for you. [This article](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal) discusses some approaches on how to use them.

Also, it is free when you assign it to running instance, but you will have to pay for it monthly if you don't use it.

---

Update

The simple way to associate elastic IP with you instance is via console.

- First allocate your address in `Elastic IPs` section of console
- Then start your instance
- Go back to `Elastic IPs` section, select address and click `Associate Address`. Then choose your running instance.

Comment: thanks one more thing when you say it is free but have to pay if i am not using it? If I am using it is it free??

Comment: The reasoning, I guess, would be that if you pay them money for your server they can throw in ip for free, but they don't want you to reserve it and not use.